# Is there a way to make two parallel threads to deal with different FBO?

Tags: multithreading, opengl

I want to build an application using OpenGL with two sub screens, following these steps:

1. I want to create two sub-threads for each sub-screen to fill their own FBO.
2. I want to draw two rectangles filled with two FBO's texture in main thread.

I know that OpenGL can only bind one FBO at a time.
So I think two sub-threads could not bind their own FBO at the same time.

Is there any way to bind different FBO in different thread at the same time?
If there is no way to achieve this, does this mean that OpenGL could only work in one thread?

Why do I need two sub thread?
For real time application, just save time.

Comment: What is a "sub thread", and how does that related to an actual "thread"?

Comment: The GPU works with only a context. Once its command-buffer is done, another context can be set as current and so procces new comands. I mean, no matter how many threads you use in CPU side, the GPU will work one by one.